# centering a file input form - html/bootstrap/angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have created a file input with an Angular directive and it seems really hard to center it for some reason:

[image]

This is my HTML, thanks for any insight.

```
<form class=".form-control">
    <center style="border: blue">
        <input class=".form-control" type="file" file-input="files" multiple>
    </center>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class=".form-group" ng-click="upload('/upload')">Upload</button>
    <button class=".form-group" ng-click="upload('/upload/save')">
        Save New Profile Picture
    </button>
    <li ng-repeat="file in files">{{file.name}}
        <img ng-src="{{imageData}}" style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px">
    </li>
</form>
```

Comment: remove '.' for class.It should be like this`class="form-control"`

Comment: when I do that it takes up the entire page and looks even worse! I tried that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you shouldn't use `center` now, it's obsolete. Now, you can do this:

```
<input class="form-control center" type="file" file-input="files" multiple>
```

CSS

```
.center { 
    margin: 0 auto !important; /* I have added the !important attribute just for debugging, you can remove it. */ 
}
```

Another trick which works is to use flexbox:

```
<form class="form-control flex">
```

CSS:

```
.flex { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; /* Optional */
}
```

Read more about flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).