# HTML File Input not centering

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a form in HTML/Tailwind CSS/ReactJS. I have created/styled the form fine, but I seem to be having issues where the file input is not properly being centered. It appears that the element has some inherent width, but it won't center itself within that space.

I've gone ahead and created a CodePen to try and represent this issue:
https://codepen.io/developerryan/pen/mdREJXo

or you can view this segment here:

```
<body>
  <div class="w-screen h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
    <form class="w-full flex flex-col items-center">
      <label class="block text-lg">Model</label>
      <input type="file" id="model" name="model" accept=".pt, .pth" multiple class="border"/>

      <label class="block text-lg mt-4">Handler</label>
      <select name="handler" id="handler" class="rounded border border-gray-400 p-1">
        <option value="">-- Please select a handler --</option>
        <option value="image_classifier">
          Image classifier
        </option>
        <option value="image_segmenter">Image segmenter</option>
        <option value="object_detector">Object detector</option>
        <option value="text_classifier">Text classifier</option>
        <option value="custom">Custom</option>
      </select>
      <div class="flex items-center justify-center font-semibold bg-blue-700 text-white rounded w-6/12 max-w-xs min-w-min my-4 h-10 hover:bg-blue-800 cursor-pointer">
        Upload
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

I have tried various different solutions, such as those listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33604946/centering-a-file-input-form-html-bootstrap-angular)
and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283338/center-file-input-html-css), but none of these seem to have any changes to my form.

The specific element that I want to be centered is the File Input, as seen here:
[image].

While the actual element is centered within the parent container, it does not look visually centered, as it is not centered within its own width/container.

Comment: What specifically is not being centred? Could you clarify some more?

Comment: Are you referring to the select not centering? It actually is centered but may visually appear not to be

Comment: I went ahead and made some edits to the question. Specifically, I want the file input to be centered within the border. @dthree

Comment: Do you mean you want "No file chosen" centred within the bordered area?

Comment: As with the associated button ideally @NeilMorgan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the input value, in this case, is something that is usually restricted for security reasons. You can always mimic the style you want yourself though.

Written example here for your consideration:

```css
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
.upload{
  display:inline-flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  position:relative;
  padding-right:22px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.upload::before{
  content:"Choose Files";
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-right:22px;
  background:grey;
}
```

```html
<label for="file" class="upload">
   File
</label>
<input id="file" type="file"/>
```